# Find Two-byte Illegal Opcodes for x86-64

Tags: c++, c, assembly, x86-64

My goal is to find what two-byte opcodes generate an illegal instruction exception.
For example, opcodes 0F 0B `UD2` raises an invalid opcode exception. The `UD2` instruction is provided for software testing to explicitly generate an invalid opcode.

**Warning** Snake oil code ahead as I'm not familiar with Windows internals.

The code below allocates a 4K page with read/write/execute permissions and using `UD2` as a starting point it tries to determine all the possible two-byte opcodes.

First, it copies the two-byte opcodes to the last two bytes of the 4K page

[image: opcodes]

then executes them and checks for the exception code.

I figured that executing the last two page bytes would either

1. Generate an illegal exception `EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION` with exactly two bytes.
2. Generate an access violation `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` when extending beyond the 4K page.

Running the code below shows interesting instructions plus many unknowns too:

```
Illegal opcodes 0x0f 0x0b (error 0xc000001d)
ud2 - Generates an invalid opcode. 
   
Illegal opcodes 0x0f 0x37 (error 0xc000001d)
getsec - Exit authenticated code execution mode.

Illegal opcodes 0x0f 0xaa (error 0xc000001d)
rsm - Resume operation of interrupted program.
```

**Question**

The hack'ish code runs fine in this opcode range

> Executing opcodes 0x0f 0x0b ... Executing opcodes 0x0f 0xcb

until it encounters these two opcodes

> 0x0f 0xcc         bswap       esp

It seems anything that manipulates the stack pointer causes issues whereby it's stuck at this point (clicking `Continue` just repeats the message)

[image: stuck]

I've tried moving the opcode execution into its own thread since they have their own stack, but that didn't help!

Is there a way to preserve the stack pointers `RSP` and `RBP` or maybe there's a simple fix to resolve it?

(Built using M$ Visual C++ 2019)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <intrin.h>

// The UD2 (0x0F, 0x0B) instruction is guaranteed to generate an invalid opcode exception.

DWORD InstructionResult;

void ExecuteOpcodes(LPVOID mem)
{
    __try
    {
        // Execute opcodes...
        ((void(*)())((unsigned char*)mem + 0xFFE))();
    }
    __except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
    {
        InstructionResult = GetExceptionCode();
    }
}

int main()
{
    LPVOID mem = VirtualAlloc(NULL, 2, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    DWORD oldProtect = VirtualProtect(mem, 2, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtect);

    // Start searching at the UD2 (0x0F, 0x0B) instruction which is guaranteed to generate an invalid opcode exception.
    for (int i = 15; i <= 255; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 11; j <= 255; j++)
        {
            // Write two byte opcodes at the 4K page end.
            *((unsigned char*)mem + 0xFFE) = i;
            *((unsigned char*)mem + 0xFFF) = j;

            printf("Executing opcodes 0x%02x 0x%02x\n",i,j);
            HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ExecuteOpcodes, mem, 0, 0);
            WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
            CloseHandle(hThread);
            if (InstructionResult == EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION)
            {
                printf("Illegal opcodes 0x%02x 0x%02x (error 0x%08x)\n", i, j, InstructionResult);
            }
        }
    }

    VirtualFree(mem, 0, MEM_RELEASE);

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Based upon the good answer about creating a child process, I've pasted the updated code here: [pastebin.com/j3NkL44q](https://pastebin.com/j3NkL44q)

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Array of illegal single-byte opcodes
int IllegalSingleByteOpcodes[] = { 0x06 ,0x07, 0x0e, 0x16, 0x17, 0x1e, 0x1f, 0x27, 0x2f, 0x37, 0x3f, 0x60, 0x61, 0xce, 0xd6 };

// Check if a given opcode is illegal
bool is_illegal_opcode(int opcode) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(IllegalSingleByteOpcodes) / sizeof(IllegalSingleByteOpcodes[0]); i++) {
        if (IllegalSingleByteOpcodes[i] == opcode) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Create and wait for a process with the given opcodes
void create_and_wait_for_process(int opcode1, int opcode2) {
    // Set up startup and process info
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    // Create command line string
    char cmdline[256];
    snprintf(cmdline, sizeof(cmdline), "IllegalOpcodes.exe %d %d", opcode1, opcode2);

    // Create process
    if (!CreateProcess(NULL, cmdline, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) {
        printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }

    // Wait for process to finish
    if (WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 1000) != WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
        TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, 0);
    }

    // Clean up handles
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}

int main() {
    // Iterate through all possible opcode pairs
    for (int opcode1 = 0; opcode1 <= 255; opcode1++) {
        // Skip illegal opcodes
        if (is_illegal_opcode(opcode1)) {
            printf("\nSkipping Illegal Opcode 0x%02x ...\n", opcode1);
            continue;
        }
        printf("\nChecking Opcode 0x%02x ...\n", opcode1);

        for (int opcode2 = 0; opcode2 <= 255; opcode2++) {
            create_and_wait_for_process(opcode1, opcode2);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


------------------- IllegalOpcodes.cpp -------------------


#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Offset to write opcodes at the 4K page end
#define CODE_PAGE_END_OFFSET 0xFFE

// Write two byte opcodes at the 4K page end and execute them
void write_and_execute_opcodes(LPVOID code_page_mem, int opcode1, int opcode2)
{
    *((unsigned char*)code_page_mem + CODE_PAGE_END_OFFSET) = opcode1;
    *((unsigned char*)code_page_mem + CODE_PAGE_END_OFFSET + 1) = opcode2;

    __try
    {
        // Execute opcodes...
        ((void(*)())((unsigned char*)code_page_mem + CODE_PAGE_END_OFFSET))();
    }
    __except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
    {
        switch (GetExceptionCode()) {
            case EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION:
                printf("{0x%02x,0x%02x},", opcode1, opcode2);
                break;
            default:
                // Ignore other exceptions
                break;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* const argv[])
{
    int opcode1 = atoi(argv[1]);
    int opcode2 = atoi(argv[2]);

    LPVOID code_page_mem = VirtualAlloc(NULL, 2, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

    DWORD old_protect = VirtualProtect(code_page_mem, 2, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &old_protect);

    write_and_execute_opcodes(code_page_mem, opcode1, opcode2);

    VirtualFree(code_page_mem, 0, MEM_RELEASE);

    return 0;
}
```

It now includes checks to avoid these single byte illegal opcodes

**32-bit Legal**

```
06              push    es
07              pop     es
0e              push    cs
16              push    ss
17              pop     ss
1e              push    ds
1f              pop     ds
27              daa
2f              das
37              aaa
3f              aas
60              pushad
61              popad
ce              into
d6              ???  <--- http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64.html#xD6
```

**64-bit Illegal**

```
06              ???
07              ???
0e              ???
16              ???
17              ???
1e              ???
1f              ???
27              ???
2f              ???
37              ???
3f              ???
60              ???
61              ???
ce              ???
d6              ???
```

Comment: _"causes issues"_ ... what issues exactly?

Comment: Corrupting the stack pointer is a fatal error, and it kills the entire process (not just the thread whose stack is corrupted).

Comment: Don't forget to check that it's not a 1-byte #UD opcode on that CPU, like `06` in 64-bit mode (`push es` in 32-bit mode).  (look for the "invalid" entries on http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64.html).  32-bit mode doesn't have any 1-byte illegal-instructions, but CPUs haven't yet repurposed most of the opcodes that AMD64 freed up.  (Most extension aim to be the same in 32-bit mode.)  e.g. after finding a candidate, put it as the last byte in a page and see if it still #UD faults instead of #PF.  If so, move to the next starting byte; no need to check different values of the 2nd byte.

Comment: Why not just look at the documentation?  Volume 2 Appendix A of [the manual](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/intel-sdm.html) has opcode maps that show what every combo of bytes does

Comment: @PeterCordes : I'd also be concerned about 2 byte `Jcc` instructions which could jump to negative displacement. If the memory page is filled with just zeroes then the results could be undefined as it executes its way back to the end of the page. All 0's would be `add [rax],al` so what happens would depend on RAX. If RAX happened to be a writeable memory address things could get interesting. I'd probably fill enough of the page with 0xcc (`int3`) to avoid problems.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Good point.  Maybe also just manually exclude `jcc`, `jmp rel8`, `ret`, and maybe some other leading bytes, like opcodes for 1-byte instructions like `push/pop reg` since there are a lot and there's no point having your brute-force search check them.  Filling the page with `CC` bytes is still a good idea.  Probably also zero other registers or better set them to non-canonical addresses, so `jmp rax` will #GP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> maybe there's a simple fix to resolve it?

The UNIX-standard way to resolve this is to do all the test execution in a child process.

When I last worked on Windows 15 years ago, creating a child process was very expensive (slow). But since you have fewer that 64K byte combinations to try, even a slow mechanism will get you all the answers in at most a few hours.

Comment: You could use `ptrace` to manipulate the child process, resetting its RIP and modifying machine-code bytes.  I assume `ptrace` isn't fast, but probably still faster than `fork`.

Comment: Windows doesn't have `fork`, but it does have WriteProcessMemory and stuff like that so you can start a process and mess with it.

Comment: Raymond noted in the comments that corrupting the stack is fatal to a process, so creating a separate process to execute the opcodes probably won't help.

Comment: @vengy: Yes it will; if the remote process died, you know something happened to it other than an illegal instruction, since illegal instructions would be caught.  Or if you're attached to it like a debugger, hopefully that will let you see the signal (or whatever Windows calls it) being delivered before the process dies from trying to do that with a corrupted stack pointer.

Comment: Creating a child process works great! I've pasted the updated code here: https://pastebin.com/j3NkL44q